# Convert Text areas text to Html with new <p> tag for each new line

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have the following html markup with a textarea in it as below.

```
<textarea id="text" rows="10">First sentence. Second sentence? Third sentence!Fourth sentence.

Fifth sentence. Six sentence.

Last sentence.
</textarea>
```

I want this to converted to the below html.

```
<p>First sentence. Second sentence? Third sentence!Fourth sentence.</P>
<p>Fifth sentence. Six sentence.</p>
<p>Last sentence.</p>
```

New `<p>` tag is created for each newline.

I have been able to get the paragraphs as an array using the below code.

```
var str = document.getElementById("text").value;
var sentences = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n|[.|!|?]\s/gi);
```

But then I can only loop through it to have a `<p>` tag each sentence. Whats the best approach?

Comment: can you post what your array looks like?  You mentioned that you can only loop through it to have a <p> for each sentence but you also said "I have been able to get the paragraphs as an array"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it looks like your regex is "looking" for the ends of the sentences with this part here: `[.|!|?]` Instead of just splitting on the newlines.

Comment: I meant as the sentences are the one in the array, how can I know a Para ending.

Comment: @KyleB My array looks like this: `["First sentence", "Second sentence", "Third sentence", "Fourth sentence", "", "Fifth sentence", ""]`

Comment: @esafwan then gforce301's answer seems correct for what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your split to be this `var sentences = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/gi);`
Then when you loop the array ignore the empty strings and wrap the non-empty ones in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: Indeed the regex must be global, otherwise `str.split(regex)` stops after the first match. But I think you can omit the 'i' flag, line breaks are not case-sensitive anyway.

Comment: Good catch on the `i` flag. I missed it and you're correct it doesn't do anything for detecting line breaks.